# Send smtp email using group email Id

Tags: email, authentication, .net-core, smtp

In my `dot-net core` application, I am sending email using `SMTP server`, it was working fine when I was using simple gmail account with password like this;

```
client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("client@gmail.com","password");
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("client@gmail.com", "user@gmail.com", subject, message);
            mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
            client.Send(mm);
```

But now, I've to send this same email using `Group email` that does not have any passowrd, so I changed my code like this;

```
client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@client.com","");
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("info@client.com", "user@gmail.com", subject, message);
            mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
            client.Send(mm);
```

But I'm getting this error;

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

Is there any way to resolve this issue or this is impossible to send email using `Group Email`?

Comment: which library exactly are you using for smtp?

Comment: System.Net.Mail;

Comment: this library is now obsolete https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0